# Create a `time` datatype in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, types

I have a model `Timeslot` with the attributes `quantity:integer`, `sold:integer`; I would like to include a `slot` attribute which represents time; I understand there is the `DateTime` datatype but this will return the whole item, date and time as one, what's the smartest way of only extracting the time? Is there something similar to use, something in the lines of:

`t.time "key", null: false`;

The idea is to then use timeslot on the front-end and display the `slot` attribute value that a user can click on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`tod` (time of day) Ruby Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/tod).

It integrates with ActiveRecord ([docs](https://github.com/JackC/tod#activerecord-attribute-support)):

```rb
# In an initializer:
ActiveModel::Type.register(:time_only, Tod::TimeOfDayType)
ActiveRecord::Type.register(:time_only, Tod::TimeOfDayType)

# In models/timeslot.rb
class Timeslot < ActiveRecord::Base
  attribute :slot, :time_only
end

timeslot = Timeslot.create(
  quantity: 11,
  sold: 3,
  slot: Tod::TimeOfDay.new(9, 30)
)

timeslot. slot
# => 09:30:00
```

Since you tagged the question with `postgresql`, you should define the column as a [`time` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-datetime.html):

```rb
class AddSlotToTimeslots < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :timeslots, :slot, "time without time zone", null: false
  end
end
```